# How to install WordPress on Heroku?

Tags: wordpress, git, heroku, github

I want to build wordpress on Heroku as the following article:

- [WordPress on Heroku: Up and Running!](http://decielo.com/articles/350/wordpress-on-heroku-up-and-running)

Here’s the step by step tutorial for getting a WordPress.org installation running on Heroku’s Cedar stack:

1. Create GitHub repo
2. Then create local repo with GitHub as the upstream for origin. Basically like it says on the new repo page:

   ```
   cd REPO-NAME
   # Create the readme file... use your favorite editor.
   # Put in something informative
   mate README.markdown
   git add .
   git remote add origin git@github.com:brookr/REPO-NAME.git
   git push -u origin master
   ```

I have downloaded Cygwin, installed Git.

1. I have created the GitHub repo according to https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo

[image]

2. `mate README.markdown` doesn't work.

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: The tutorial is wrong. Egregiously wrong. After you do `git add .`, you need to commit using `git commit` before you try to push anything with `git push`.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work with a different editor, as suggested in my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [the article you linked](http://decielo.com/articles/350/wordpress-on-heroku-up-and-running), `mate` is simply an example text editor:

> `mate README.markdown # Create the readme file... use your favorite editor. Put in something informative`

In this case it's the [command-line interface to Textmate](http://manual.macromates.com/en/using_textmate_from_terminal.html), which is only available on OSX.

You could use Sublime Text, Emacs, Vim, Notepad++, almost anything. Even Notepad *might* work, though its Windows-only line endings might muss things up.

As Cupcake [mentions in the comments](http://manual.macromates.com/en/using_textmate_from_terminal.html), the Git commands in the tutorial will need some tweaking as well. `git add` *stages* changes, which then get committed with `git commit`. `git push` pushes committed changes, so if you don't `git commit` you won't be pushing anything.

There may be other minor bugs in the article as well, though it looks reasonably close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The repo on github is empty. There is nothing to clone.

The "git clone REMOTE LOCAL" makes/names the local dir. So your next command should have been "cd 99catfacts.com" had the remote existed to be cloned.

> How can I do this?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/php

It's beta, but that is better than; clone this, hit moving target x, have WP site.